# ¿alguien sabe como asignar un fetch_assoc() o un mysqli_fetch_array() hacia una variable?

Tags: php, mysql, jquery

gracias por leer mi publicación.

llevo horas intentando hacer una asignación hacia una variable desde un fetch_assoc() o un mysqli_fetch_array(), este es mi código:

```
$dba = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'prueba');

$salida = "";

$query = "SELECT * FROM Clientes WHERE idClientes=''";

if (isset($_POST['consulta'])) {
    $q = $dba->real_escape_string($_POST['consulta']);
    $query = "SELECT * FROM Clientes WHERE idClientes = '$q' ";
}

$resultado = $dba->query($query);

while($filas = $resultado->mysql_fetch_array(resultado)){
    $name = $filas['Nombre_Clientes'];
    $phone1 = $filas['Telefono1'];
    $mail1 = $filas['Email1'];
    $company = $filas['Compania'];
    $city1 = $filas['Ciudad1'];
    $state1 = $filas['Estado1'];
}
```

mi segundo código fallido  para pruebas fue

```
$dba = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'prueba');

$query = "SELECT * FROM Clientes WHERE idClientes=''";
if (isset($_POST['consulta'])) {
    $q = $dba->real_escape_string($_POST['consulta']);
    $query = "SELECT * FROM Clientes WHERE idClientes = '$q' ";
}
$resultado = $dba->query($query);

if ($resultado->num_rows>0) {

while ($filas = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)){
    $name = $filas[1];
    $phone1 = $filas[2];
    $mail1 = $filas[3];
    $company = $filas[4];
    $city1 = $filas[5];
    $state1 = $filas[6];
}}else{}
```

el SQL no es muy complejo

```
SELECT `idClientes`, `Nombre_Clientes`, `Compania`, `Direccion1`, `Ciudad1`, `Estado1`, `Telefono1`, `Email1`, `Direccion2`, `Ciudad2`, `Estado2`, `Telefono2`, `Email2`, `RFC`, `Status` FROM `clientes`
```

base de datos y conexion en perfecto funcionamiento.

si la pregunta es el porqué deseo hacer esto, es porque sigo el tutorial de [una persona](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OASBM4heElI) y logré hacer que mostrara los registros en text fields en lugar de una tabla, pero ahora no se como enviar la información del text field hacia una variable porque la forma en que capturo la información en el text field es la siguiente

```
if ($resultado->num_rows>0) {

    $salida.="";

    while ($fila = $resultado->fetch_assoc()) {

        $salida.=" 

        <div id='datos'>
        <div class='form-group'>
        <label class='col-sm-3 control-label'>Nombre del Cliente</label>
            <div class='col-sm-5'>
                <input type='text' name='name' class='form-control' value=".$fila['Nombre_Clientes']."  disabled>
            </div>
        </div>";
}
}else{
     }
```

la cual funciona sin ningun problema para visualización y no para almacenamiento, porque almaceno mediante el método

```
   $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($dba, $_POST['name']);
```

cualquier ayuda es bienvenida.

edito: adjunto nuevo metodo fallido:

```
if (isset($_POST['consulta'])) {
    $q = $dba->real_escape_string($_POST['consulta']);
    $query = "SELECT * FROM Clientes WHERE idClientes = '$q' ";
    $query1 = "SELECT Nombre_Clientes FROM Clientes WHERE idClientes = '$q' ";
    $query2 = "SELECT Telefono1 FROM Clientes WHERE idClientes = '$q' ";
    $query3 = "SELECT EMail1 FROM Clientes WHERE idClientes = '$q' ";
    $query4 = "SELECT Compania FROM Clientes WHERE idClientes = '$q' ";
    $query5 = "SELECT Ciudad1 FROM Clientes WHERE idClientes = '$q' ";
    $query6 = "SELECT Estado1 FROM Clientes WHERE idClientes = '$q' ";
}

$resultado = $dba->query($query);

$name = $dba->query($query1);
$phone1 = $dba->query($query2);
$mail1 = $dba->query($query3);
$company = $dba->query($query4);
$city1 = $dba->query($query5);
$state1 = $dba->query($query6);

$res1 = $name.'';
$res2 = $phone1.'';
$res3 = $mail1.'';
$res4 = $company1.'';
$res5 = $city1.'';
$res6 = $state1.'';
```